# SSRS reports dynamics crm have current record id used as parameter

Tags: dynamics-crm, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Hi for my ssrs report In dynamics crm I require that when the report is ran against a certain record, the records passes the record id so that only the relevant results are displayed.

How is this possible ? Steps provided will be great also

Reports are created using SQL.

Run against campaign entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS reports for CRM have special parameters that enable this for you. To filter by selected records (or the current record you have open) you can utilise a hidden parameter called "CRM_Filtered[Entity]" where entity is the relevant entity you are linking the report to.

In your case, i.e. for the campaign entity, this hidden parameter will be called CRM_FilteredCampaign. For a SQL report this will be a text parameter and will be set to something like this (set by CRM when you run the report)

```sql
select campaign0.* from FilteredCampaign as "campaign0"
```

I do not have a report to hand to check exactly what the SQL will contain, so it might not be exact. But you get the idea. There are several ways to embed this in your report, but you could do so in a rudimentary fashion like this in a dataset:

```sql
 declare @sql as nVarchar(max)
 set @sql = 'SELECT c.campaignid FROM (' + @CRM_FilteredCampaign + ') as c'
 exec(@sql)
```

Expanding on this, i.e. rather than executing text SQL in your main dataset, you can instead simplify the usage by creating a dataset/parameter combo based off the text. In effect, convert the SQL text to a list of values instead.

So add the above SQL to its own DataSet (for this example called `DS_FilteredCampaign`).

Once you have created `DS_FilteredCampaign` make sure you click on the `Refresh Fields` button. Type in the following instead of `<null>` for the parameter value:

```sql
select c.* from FilteredCampaign as c
```

Once that comes back click on Ok to save the DataSet.

Next, create another hidden text parameter (e.g. `Int_FilteredCampaign`) and tell it to get its default value from a DataSet (not its available values, its default value). Point the values at `DS_FilteredCampaign`, and you should be able to select `campaignid` as its value field. This in effect makes the parameter an array of Ids you can reference in your main DataSet

Now it's much more usable as you can reference it in your SQL something like this in your main DataSet:

```sql
select c.*
from FilteredCampaign c
inner join ActivityPointer ap on ...
inner join FilteredAccount a on ...
where c.campaignid in (@Int_FilteredCampaign)
```

The important piece being **`where c.campaignid in (@Int_FilteredCampaign)`**

Summary Steps:

- You have a main DataSet called something like dsMain
- Create a new parameter called CRM_FiltetedCampaign
- Create a DataSet (DS_FilteredCampaign) that executes the SQL passed into CRM_FilteredCampaign
- Refresh Fields on the data set to get the campaignid field
- Create a text parameter (Int_FilteredCampaign) that retrieves its **default** value using the new dataset (DS_FilteredCampaign) using campaignid for the value
- Reference this new parameter in you dsMain dataset

Comment: How would I be able to fit this in with the current sql query and dataset which currently has 3 joins to the campaign, activity pointer and campaign response entities.

Comment: There are many ways to incorporate the parameter and make it more usable. I'll expand the question shortly with this example, but a summary of how you can do it is create a dataset based off the parameter and just exec it. Then base a parameter off that and reference it in your report. I'll expand the question with an example...

Comment: So do I create another dataset to set the parameter and then have it referenced in existing dataset ?

Comment: If you mean the "CRM_FilteredCampaigm" parameter, no. CRM will set the parameter for you. All you have to do is make sure it is available for it to use. Then you can create a dataset that calls 'exec' on that param, and reference that dataset by another param you create. Basically just to convert their param to a list of ids that is easier to reference in the "real" dataset.

Comment: Sorry I meant how do i make the parameter available to use , with my existing sql dataset or do I create a new data set with the query above ? Sorry for so many questions but I appreciate your help

Comment: I've added summary steps to the answer. But in short you create a new dataset to exec your CRM special param. Then you create another parameter (an internal one that only the report uses) that fetches its list of values from this new dataset. What happens in your report is this: Report loads and references dsMain which executes; this references the internal parameter (Int_FilteredCampaign) in its query; this parameter executes the secondary dataset you created and gets a list of campaignids; dsMain is now filtered by campaignids passed in.

Comment: I just got access to a report that I did this in and one of my steps wasn't clear... I have updated the answer, but you the new internal parameter (Int_FilteredCampaign) is just a text param that gets it's *default* values from the dataset.

Comment: @KCodeR when you're next on let me know if it still doesn't work. We could possibly move this discussion to chat instead and try resolve it quicker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138004/discussion-between-kcoder-and-conor-gallagher).

Comment: @KCodeR Updated as per discussion to include refreshing of parameters, and to make the answer read a bit better.

Comment: The expected parameter has not been supplied for the report.  have you ever experienced this error when running report in CRM? @ConnorGallagher

Comment: This sounds like a slightly different problem I'd have a few questions about. I'd raise a new question so that you could give us more details in regards to this one. For example, running the report through CRM vs Visual Studio etc.